# How to add data to kenisis firehose through lambda function using awssdk for .net?

Tags: c#, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-sdk-net

I have created lambda function in c# using awssdk version 3 which pass json data to firehose stream which produce the result with an error in S3 bucket

> "Invalid output structure: Please check your function and make sure the processed records contain valid result status of Dropped, Ok, or ProcessingFailed."

here is my lambda function code

```
AmazonKinesisFirehoseConfig config = new AmazonKinesisFirehoseConfig();
config.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2;
AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient firehoseClient = new AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient(config);

string dataAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sq);
byte[] dataAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataAsJson);
string base64Data = System.Convert.ToBase64String(dataAsBytes);            

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64Data)))
{
    try
    {
        PutRecordRequest requestRecord = new PutRecordRequest();
        requestRecord.DeliveryStreamName = MyDeliveryStreamName;

        Record record = new Record();
        record.Data = memoryStream;
        requestRecord.Record = record;                    

        PutRecordResponse responseRecord = await firehoseClient.PutRecordAsync(requestRecord);

        return responseRecord.RecordId;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this dataAsBytes itself sufficient to feed to MemoryStream? Do you have to base64 encode the bytes to string and again to bytes? using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(dataAsBytes))